# merge two arrays of objects without duplicates of certain values

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, javascript-objects

I got these two arrays of objects:

Array 1:

```
[{myObject1: "xx"},
{myObject2: "yy"},
{myObject3: "zz"}, 
{myObject4: "tt"}, 
{myObject5: "bb"}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{myOtherObject1: "aa"},
{myObject2: "bb"},
{myAnotherObject3: "zz"}, 
{oneMoreObject4: "kk"}]
```

The goal is to change Array 2 into an array without the values that are duplicated:  **"zz" and "bb"**

So the result would be:

```
[{myOtherObject1: "aa"},{oneMoreObject4: "kk"}]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please share what have you tried too.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

I assumed the input objects could have multiple keys

```js
let input1 = [
  { myObject1: "xx" },
  { myObject2: "yy" },
  { myObject3: "zz" },
  { myObject4: "tt" },
  { myObject5: "bb" }
];

let map = {};
input1.forEach(x => {
    Object.values(x).forEach(y=>map[y]=true);
});

let input2 = [
  { myOtherObject1: "aa" },
  { myObject2: "bb" },
  { myAnotherObject3: "zz" },
  { oneMoreObject4: "kk" }
];

let result = input2.filter(x => {
    return !(Object.values(x).some(y => map[y]))
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
const array1 = [{myObject1: "xx"},{myObject2: "yy"},{myObject3: "zz"}, {myObject4: "tt"}, {myObject5: "bb"}];

const array2 = [{myOtherObject1: "aa"},{myObject2: "bb"},{myAnotherObject3: "zz"}, {oneMoreObject4: "kk"}];

const result = array2.filter(i => {
  const value = Object.values(i)[0];
  return !array1.find(f => Object.values(f)[0] === value);
});
// Expected output: [{myOtherObject1: "aa"},{oneMoreObject4: "kk"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const a = [{a: 1}, {b: 2}, {c: 3}, {d: 4}, {e: 5}];
const b = [{a: 6}, {b: 7}, {c: 1}, {d: 2}, {e: 3}];

const result = b.filter(obj1 => {
    const value = Object.values(obj1)[0];
    return a.every(obj2 => Object.values(obj2)[0] !== value);
});
```

Well, a little explanation. I believe that it will helpful to others.

`const result = b.filter(obj1 => {`
Makes a filtering trough `b` array, to get a new array which will be contained only elements that returned with a condition below. Have to iterate every object in the array, so `obj1` means "current" object which filter is iterating now.

`const value = Object.values(obj1)[0];`
Getting a value from an object from an array, because an object has `key` and `value` part, that means `key: value` pair and, it's a same like `a: 6` as the first element of `b` array. Literally, in case of `{a: 6}` object value will be `6` here.

`return a.every(obj2 => ...`
For each of item from `b` element which we have iterated in the filter, we should also iterate trough `a` array, to compare the items which the same or not.

`Object.values(obj2)[0] !== value`
Well, here is left side contains also the value, but from `obj2` object, just keep in mind that `obj2` iterates `a` array. And then we've been comparing this values to exclude the objects who value will be repeated.

Comment: Please explain your code a little, this makes it more helpful for OP and future readers, as well as increasing it's long term value

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've added the explanation. Thanks.